# Passport authenticate middleware with encrypted username using bcrypt

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am needing some assistance with how to use passport.authenticate() when the username has been encrypted using the NPM bcryptjs library.

For example, when I create a user I encrypt the username before using passport.js to create and save the user to MongoDB. Then in my route to log in, I pass in passport.authenticate("local") as the middleware which does all checking against the username and password.

In this scenario the username is actually the encrypted string, is there a way to use the passport.authenticate to check against the passed in username and an encrypted string?

Pieces of my code that make up the registration and login route.

```
userParam.username = bcrypt.hashSync(userParam.username);

        userModel.create(new userModel(userParam), userParam.password , (error) => {
            if (error) {
                response.Error = error;
                return Promise.resolve(response);
            } 
        });

        //Save user
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            req.session.save((error) => {
                if (error) {
                    response.Error = error;
                    return Promise.resolve(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

Login route.

```
app.get('/api/user/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res) {
    req.session.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ message: "Failed to sign in", err });
        }

        res.json({ status: "Signed In", authenticated: req.isAuthenticated(), user: req.user, session: req.session });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I was able to dig deeper on the documentation for passport.js and I found that the passport.authenticate() was handled by the instance of passport.use(new LocalStrategy(...)). In that method, I was able to add my own custom logic to handle checking against an encrypted username.

Before I was just using

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

And I was able to update for my use case performing the following....

````
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
            async function(username, password, done) {
              let allUsers = await User.find({});

              if(username.length == 7) {

                  for(var i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
                    if (bcrypt.compareSync(username, allUsers[i].username)) {
                        username = allUsers[i].username ;
                        break;
                    }
                  }
              }

              User.findOne({ username }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                     return done(err); 
                }
                if (!user) {
                  return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
                }
                if (!password) {
                  return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
                }
                return done(null, user);
              });
            }
          ));
    ```
````